# Как лучше сверстать этот заголовок линией?

Tags: html, css

В дизайн-макете блок выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сверстал его аналогичным по макету. В десктопе все выглядит нормально, однако при адаптиве линия заезжает на заголовок. Как лучше мне сверстать подобный блок?

```css
.for-whom__content__subtitle {
  margin: 40px 0 46px 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.for-whom__content__subtitle .line {
  width: 88%;
}

.section-subtitle {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
  }

.line {
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: #F57B51;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.line::before,
.line::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #F57B51;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-45%) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-45%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(-45%) rotate(45deg);
}

.line::before {
  left: 0;
}

.line::after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="for-whom__content__subtitle">
              <h4 class="section-subtitle">По стажу</h4>
              <div class="line"> </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Данный блок лучше сверстать через псевдоелемент ::after чтобы не загромождать разметку "лишними" пустыми дивами) а разместить можно с помощью инлайн-блока или абсолютно

Comment: Да, изначально я так и сверстал. Однако там есть ромбы по обе стороны этой линии. И позиционирование линии абсолютно перекрывает (зачеркивает) заголовок. Инлайн-блок здесь не подходит, если родитель псевдоэлемента сам заголовок.
Необходимо, чтобы был заголовок, допустим, занимающий ширину 20% (в макете они все разной длинны), а остальное пространство занимала линия

Answer (score 1):

Помогает свойство `flex-grow: 1;`.

```css
.section-subtitle {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.section-subtitle h4 {
  font-family: "FiveYearsLater";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.section-subtitle::after {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: #F57B51;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-subtitle for-whom__content__subtitle">
              <h4>По стажу</h4>
            </div>
```